# UITableView crashes on scrolling

Tags: iphone, uitableview

UITableView is crashing on scrolling . Here is the sample code..

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

 NSLog(@"Total Count: %d",count);
 return [ObjectArray count] ;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];




    if (cell == nil) {

  cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

  cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
  cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.0];
  cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10.0];

  [cell.textLabel sizeToFit];
  [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];


    }

 // Configure the cell.

 NSLog(@"Row Number %d", indexPath.row);
 cell.textLabel.text = [ObjectArray name];
 return cell;
}
```

In console I can see Total count = 22.

```
Row Number 0
Row NUmber 1
.
.
Row Number 21 (This row number will pull the last object from ObjectArray)
```

Now if I try to scroll it crashes...why? Can anyone help me with this ...

Comment: Please reformat your code correctly and post the stack trace of the crash.

Comment: Can you also mention more about the ObjectArray. At the moment ObjectArray is being used like it's not an Array. ie. [ObjectArray name]... not pulling any object from an 'array'

Comment: Also, you should probably make sure your datasource is retained. Often times, crashes on scroll are as a result of trying to access an empty/nil datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand this line of code

```
         cell.textLabel.text = [ObjectArray name];
```

If ObjectArray is a NSArray instance, then it would not respond to that selector. And anyway you probably want to return smth like

```
         cell.textLabel.text = [ObjectArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
```

Comment: MY bad..I tried to modify the actual code so ended up confusing you.

ObjectArray is an NSMutableArray. I am confident that ObjectArray is getting populated with object type “MyObject”.
MyObject has instance variable called “name” and “age”.
So here is the modified code for
NSLog(@"Row Number %d", indexPath.row);
 cell.textLabel.text = [ObjectArray name];

MyObject *temp  = [ObjectArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel.text = [temp name];
[temp release]

My development machine is at work. So writing this in notepad. Please ignore any syntax error.

Comment: [temp release] - you are releasing it, so when your table view is trying to access that item in the second time it is already freed. remove that line

Comment: The reason is that here the temp.name variable is retained and not the temp itself

Comment: @Max then how come I am able to print all objects ..?? Can you help me change the code ..??

Comment: well, i've already told you: first time when you accessing the item in array, it's ok. but then you're releasing it, so the second time when we try to access it - the link is invalid. just remove the [temp release]  line

Comment: Max..thanks for speedy response. If I don't release the object won't it create a memory leak ..??

Comment: why? there is no retain here MyObject *temp = [ObjectArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]. you are just obtaining the reference to an object

Comment: great..I will test this tomorrow..!!! Thanks a lot Max.. appreciate all the help.

Comment: @Max I tested this first thing in the morning.....guess what..it worked...!!!Thanks again ...!!!